# Unable to guess how to get a Doctrine instance

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony

I have been through the process of updating my project from Symfony 2.8 to Symfony 3 and am now reworking one of my controllers but am having some trouble.

I have a Child entity and controller.  The controller has a base route

```
/**
* Child controller.
*
* @Route("/profile/{parentName}/{childName}")
*/
```

with an action

```
/**
 * Finds and displays a Child entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}", name="child_show")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template()
 */
public function showAction(Child $child)
{
    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($child);

    return array(
        'child' => $child,
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    );
}
```

However I don't want the page URL to be domain.com/parentname/childname/id I want it to be domain.com/parentname/childname

In 2.8 my controller was

```
/**
* Child controller.
*
* @Route("/profile/{parentName}/{childName}")
*/


/**
 * Finds and displays a Child entity.
 *
 * @Route("/", name="child_show")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template()
 */
public function showAction($childName)
{

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $entity = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Child')->findOneByName($childName);
    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Child entity.');
    }

    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($childName);

    return array(
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    );
}
```

and it worked as I wanted.

However if in my updated controller I modify the route annotation on showAction to

```
/**
* @Route("/", name="child_show")
* @Method("GET")
* @Template()
*/
```

I get an error *Unable to guess how to get a Doctrine instance from the request information.* I guess because the Id is needed to get the correct instance of Child?  However childName ($name) in the Child entity is also unique.

I'm a bit stuck with this.  Can anyone advise what I am doing wrong?  I want to be able to have a route for the child profile page that doesn't contain the ID but uses the child's name to return the info required.

Update in response to some comments / questions - below is my Child entity

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use AppBundle\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
* Child
*
* @ORM\Table()
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\ChildRepository")
* @UniqueEntity("name")
*/

class Child
{

/**
 * @var integer
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
 */
private $name;

/*
* Todo - figure out how to use a date type for dateofbirth below and as well in users.yml fixtures file
*/

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="date_of_birth", type="datetime")
 */
private $dateOfBirth;

//todo find ot why the parent variable here and Id variable in AppBundle:User are not mapped correctly
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="id")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE")
 */

private $parent;

/**
 * @return User
 */
public function getParent()
{
    return $this->parent;
}

/**
 * @param User $parent
 */
public function setParent(User $parent)
{
    $this->parent = $parent;
}


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set name
 *
 * @param string $name
 *
 * @return Child
 */
public function setName($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get name
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}


/**
 * Set dateOfBirth
 *
 * @param \DateTime $dateOfBirth
 *
 * @return Child
 */
public function setDateOfBirth($dateOfBirth)
{
    $this->dateOfBirth = $dateOfBirth;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get dateOfBirth
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getDateOfBirth()
{
    return $this->dateOfBirth;
}
}
```

and modified the showAction to

```
/**
* Child controller.
*
* @Route("/profile/{parentName}/{name}")
*/

/**
 * Finds and displays a Child entity.
 *
 * @Route("/", name="child_show")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template()
 */
public function showAction(Child $name)
{
    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($name);

    return array(
        'child' => $name,
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    );
}
```

but I now get an error *AppBundle\Entity\Child object not found.*

```
ERROR - Uncaught PHP Exception  

Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException:     "AppBundle\Entity\Child object not found." at /Library/WebServer/Documents/story-project/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 7183
```

Comment: Are `parentName` and `childName` the exact names of the attributes used to match and get the entity? If not, you should use the ParamConverter annotation.

Comment: @Sogara no they aren't i'll check this out a little later thanks!  parent defined on Child entity like
    *@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="id")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE")
     */

    private $parent;

however I think I have other corrections t make in this version too as currently I can put any value for parentName in the URL (domain.com/john/sam/56 and domain.com/mary/sam/56 both work) and so long as the child ID is in the url the child is returned.

Comment: @Sogara I've updated my question to use the same attributes but I now get  an AppBundle\Entity\Child object not found error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entity is not found, because Doctrine can't find a Child with name `{name}` and parentName `parentName`... Which seems legit, since parentName does not exist in the Child entity.

Two solutions :

1 - Never tried, but might work : create getParentName() in Child and make it `return $this->parent->getName()`

2 - Add a ParamConverter annotation on the top of your Controller Action:

```
/**
 * Finds and displays a Child entity.
 *
 * @Route("/", name="child_show")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template()
 * @ParamConverter("child", class="AppBundle:Child", options={"name" = "name"})
 */
 public function showAction(Child $child)
```

This way, the Converter will only consider the argument "name" when attempting to retrieve your Child entity... (is that really what you want by the way?)
Don't forget to `use` ParamConverter in your Controller.

Comment: thanks for this - works perfectly!  I actually would like to take parentName and childName (now name) into account when retrieving a profile but I guess I can play with additional ParamConverters to sort this.  A whole new feature to learn about :).  Will mark this as the answer.  Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks! :)
I'm not completely sure you can use ParamConverter to take into account a field from a relationship, but give it a try, and otherwise you can do this manually in your Controller. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you have unique fields you should mark them as unique in your entity definitions:

In [the `@column` annotation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#column):

```
/**
 * @Column(type="string", length=32, unique=true, nullable=false)
 */
protected $name;
```

Or for [other unique constraints](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#uniqueconstraint):

```
/**
 * @entity
 * @Table(name="child", uniqueConstraints{   
 *     @UniqueConstraint(name="name_something_unique", columns = {"name", "something"})
 * })
 */
```

If you add the `@column` unique constraint for `name` then your `findOneByName` will probably work as expected.

You can for now also make it work like this:

```
$childs = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Child')->findBy( array('name' => $childName ));
```

Then you get a `Collection` and if you are sure it is unique you can simply get the [first](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.1/class-Doctrine.Common.Collections.Collection.html#_first) element if the collection is not [empty](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.1/class-Doctrine.Common.Collections.Collection.html#_isEmpty)...

```
if( ! $childs->isEmpty() ){

    $first = $childs->first();

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Wilt - I'll take a proper look a little later today.  I do have name as unique on my Child entity  @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255 but need to check out some of your other suggestions

Comment: I have posted my Child Entity and seem to have the correct annotations as you described but I'm getting an AppBundle\Entity\Child object not found error.
Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @StuartBrown Is it in the correct folder? Make sure you remove all white space between the top of the class and the annotations...

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error message, but I guess, in a bit different situation than yours.

I needed to render a particular article in its own twig template. So I had:

`<a href="{{ path('article_show', { 'title': article.title|lower }) }}" class="pull-right">Read More</a>`, where `'title'` was the name of a column in a table.

But in my controller class I had:

```
/**
 * @Route("/article/{name}", name="article_show")
 * @Method("GET")
 */
public function showAction(Article $article)
{
    return $this->render('AppBundle:Article:show.html.twig', ['article'=>$article]);
}
```

That `{name}` in the `@Route` changed everything. I mean that was causing the error. So I needed to make sure that instead of `{name}` I should've have `{title}` as in the `'title'` part of my anchor element (`{ 'title': article.title|lower }`).

Answer (score 0):

@Dan Costinel

I got the same error message, but I guess, in a little bit different way than yours.

*"Unable to generate a URL for the named route "users_delete" as such route does not exist"*

**I had forgotten to add the requested {variable} in the route in the routing.yml**

```
users_delete:
    path:     /{id}/modifier
    defaults: { _controller: ReservationBundle:Users:modifier }
```

Thats why my controller couldn't access the information expected in the $request variable:

public function modifierAction(Request $request, Users $user)
    {}

But that's your anwer that put me in the right track:

> That {name} in the @Route changed everything. I mean that was causing
>   the error. So I needed to make sure that instead of {name} I should've
>   have {title} as in the 'title' part of my anchor element ({ 'title':
>   article.title|lower }).